# Two solutions to leetcode 127.wordLadder

Tags: python, programming-challenge, comparative-review, graph, memory-optimization

I am working on [Word Ladder - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/)

> Given two words (*beginWord* and *endWord*), and a dictionary's word list, find the length of shortest transformation sequence from *beginWord* to *endWord*, such that:
>
> 1. Only one letter can be changed at a time.
> 2. Each transformed word must exist in the word list. Note that *beginWord* is *not* a transformed word.
>
> **Note:**
>
> - Return 0 if there is no such transformation sequence.
> - All words have the same length.
> - All words contain only lowercase alphabetic characters.
> - You may assume no duplicates in the word list.
> - You may assume *beginWord* and *endWord* are non-empty and are not the same.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> beginWord = "hit",
> endWord = "cog",
> wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]
>
> Output: 5
>
> Explanation: As one shortest transformation is "hit" -> "hot" -> "dot" -> "dog" -> "cog",
> return its length 5.
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> beginWord = "hit"
> endWord = "cog"
> wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log"]
>
> Output: 0
>
> Explanation: The endWord "cog" is not in wordList, therefore no possible transformation.
> ```

Approach 1: Breadth First Search

```py
class Solution1:
    def ladderLength(self, beginWord, endWord, wordList):
          """
        :type beginWord: str
        :type endWord: str
        :type wordList: List[str]
        :rtype step: int
        """
        visited = set()
        wordSet = set(wordList)

        queue = [(beginWord, 1)]

        while len(queue) > 0: #queue is not empty 
            word, step = queue.pop(0)
            #logging.debug(f"word: {word}, step:{step}")

            #base case 
            if word == endWord:
                return step #get the result.
            if word in visited: #better than multiple conditions later.
                continue
            #visited.add(word) # paint word as visited

            #traverse all the  variants 
            for i in range(len(word)):
                for j in range(0, 26): 
                    ordinal = ord('a') + j
                    next_word = word[0:i] + chr(ordinal) + word[i + 1:]
                    #logging.debug(f"changed_word: {next_word}")
                    if next_word in wordSet: 
                        queue.append((next_word, step + 1)) #contiue next stretch 
            visited.add(word) # paint word as visited

        return 0
```

> Runtime: 740 ms, faster than 22.79% of Python3 online submissions for Word Ladder.
>
> Memory Usage: 15.9 MB, less than 13.09% of Python3 online submissions for Word Ladder.

Approach 2: Bidirectional Breadth First Search

```py
class Solution2(object):
    def ladderLength(self, beginWord, endWord, wordList):
        #base case
        if (endWord not in wordList) or (not endWord) or (not beginWord) or (not wordList):
            return 0
        size = len(beginWord)
        word_set = set(wordList)    
        forwards, backwards = {beginWord}, {endWord}
        visited = set()
        step = 0
        while forwards and backwards:
            step += 1 #treat the first word as step 1
            if len(forwards) > len(backwards): 
                forwards, backwards = backwards, forwards #switch process
            #logging.debug(f"step: {step}, forwards: {forwards}, backwords: {backwards}")

            neighbors= set()   
            for word in forwards:#visit words on this level
                if word in visited: continue

                for i in range(size):
                    for c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
                        next_word = word[:i] + c + word[i+1:]
                        if next_word in backwards: return step +  1 #terminating case
                        if next_word in word_set: neighbors.add(next_word)
                        #logging.debug(f"next_word{next_word}, step: {step}")
                visited.add(word) #add visited word as the final step 
            forwards = neighbors 
        #logging.debug(f"final: {step}")
        return 0
```

> Runtime: 80 ms, faster than 98.38% of Python3 online submissions for Word Ladder.
>
> Memory Usage: 13.6 MB, less than 28.37% of Python3 online submissions for Word Ladder.

TestCase

```
class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution2()

    def test_1(self):
        beginWord = "hit" 
        endWord = "cog"
        wordList = ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log","cog"]
        #logging.debug(f"beginWord: {beginWord}\nendword:{endWord}\nwordList{wordList}")
        check = self.solution.ladderLength(beginWord, endWord, wordList)
        answer = 5
        self.assertEqual(check, answer)


    def test_2(self):
        beginWord = "hit" 
        endWord = "cog"
        wordList =  ["hot","dot","dog","lot","log"]
        check = self.solution.ladderLength(beginWord, endWord, wordList)
        answer = 0
        self.assertEqual(check, answer)
```

The memory usage in both solution is bad.